# Call function which was load in footer

Tags: javascript, php, html, timezone

In a php foreach, I would convert a date using the client timezone.

Actually, it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<body>

  <?php foreach ($topic as $post) { ?>
    <span id="date">
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.write(window.date('<?php echo $date;?>'));
      </script>
    </span>
  <?php } ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function date(VarDate) {
    var b = VarDate.split(/[: ]/g);
    var m = {jan:0, feb:1, mar:2, apr:3, may:4, jun:5, jul:6, aug:7, sep:8, oct:9, nov:10, dec:11};
    var isoTime = Date.UTC(b[7], m[b[1].toLowerCase()], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
    var date = new Date(isoTime).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, {day: '2-digit', month:'2-digit', year:'2-digit'});
    var time = new Date(isoTime).toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
    return time + ' · ' + date;
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

It works when I put the function before the loop but scripts are launched in footer to optimize the loading.

I'm looking for something better. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Try `document.write(date('<?php echo $date;?>'));`

Comment: If you want to reuse the function then put the function in different js file and include that file in header.

Comment: Try writing `document.write(window.date('<?php echo $date;?>'));` in side `$(document).ready(function(){ --here--  })`

Comment: @VipinSingh I asking for put the function in footer.

Answer (score 0):

As Sanchit said, you could rewrite the

```
    document.write(window.date('<?php echo $date;?>'));
```

part, as follows (if you use jQuery)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        // write here where needed: using jQuery the $('') approach is the easiest way
   });
```

In this way, the script is executed once all the scripts are loaded in the page and all the functions are defined. Anyway, in this case if you move this function definition in the footer the bytes saved are partially used by the overhead required to fire the script when the page is ready.

Depending on the number of $post in the $topic, this approach could slow down the loading time. Maybe, it would be faster to put the definition in an external Javascript (so it can be cached by the browser) included in the header of the page.

Comment: Because scripts are loading in footer: function date(), JQuery lib, etc... It doesn't work. This error happens: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(document).ready(function(){...